# TCL/Expect encoding

Tags: tcl, asterisk, expect

I have an el5 system with "tcl" and "expect", intended use for use Asterisk Call Manager / 1.0, I make a telnet connection to send messages (use of VGSMII, with vgsm_sms_tx command).
When I actually make the connection in telnet and write the commands, and the text of the messages, no problem. Instead when I do it to the script, Asterisk Call Manager is unable to send messages with special characters (example: € èé)
The O.system uses en_US.utf-8 as the encoding.
TCL should use iso-8859 (if I'm not wrong).
I tried to set up

```
set var1 [encoding convertto utf-8 $var0]
```

but nothing seems to change...
I also tried with the gsm0338

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm no expert on expect, but I imagine one will be along in a minute. In the meantime, please can you supply as much of the script as you are comfortable to share. Also, exactly where are you putting the code fragment you quote, and how do you know that "Asterisk Call Manager is unable to send messages with special characters"? Error from Asterisk? Don't receive them in your script? Sadly, I'm no expert on encodings either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, i convert only the messages in base64, with this works fine.
i follow this(in view mode, doesn't view anything):
http://open.voismart.it/index.php?title=VGSM_Manager_Interface&action=edit

```
    =vgsm_sms_tx Action=

The vGSM Asterisk's channel driver provides a manager action to send Short Messages (SMS). The action is named '''vgsm_sms_tx'''.

If the message does not contain characters in the [http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/default_alphabet.html GSM default alphabet] the message will be sent with UCS2 but the available characters will be reduced to 80.

In pre-0.21.0 releases the action was named '''VGSMsmstx'''. This name is now deprecated and vgsm_sms_tx will be supported starting from 0.21.0.

== Parameters ==

{| class="wikitable"
!Header
!Usage
!Description
|-
|'''To'''
|Mandatory
|The phone number to which to send the SMS. It may be in national format (347123456) or international format (+39347123456). The 00 or other operator-specific prefixes are not supported.
|-
|'''X-SMS-ME'''
|Optional
|Specifies the interface on which the SMS is sent. If not specified the SMS is sent on the first available interface. Huntgroups are supported using the <tt>huntgroup:name</tt> syntax, but sending will not currently be retried if there is a failure on the chosen module. Also, only sequential hunting is supported.
|-
|'''X-SMS-SMCC-Number'''
|Optional
|If present, forces the use of a specific Service Center.
|-
|'''X-SMS-Reject-Duplicates'''
|Optional
|Maps to TP-Reject-Duplicates (TP-RD), Ref. TS 100 901, §9.2.3.27
|-
|'''X-SMS-Reply-Path'''
|Optional
|Maps to TP-Reply-Path (TP-RP), Ref. TS 100 901, §9.2.3.17
|-
|'''X-SMS-Status-Report-Request'''
|Optional
|Maps to TP-Status-Report-Request (TP-SRR), Ref. TS 100 901, §9.2.3.5
|-
|'''X-SMS-Message-Reference'''
|Optional
|Maps to TP-Message-Reference (TP-MR), Ref. TS 100 901, §9.2.3.6
|-
|'''X-SMS-Validity-Period'''
|Optional
|Maps to TP-Validity-Period (TP-VP), Ref. TS 100 901, §9.2.3.12, specifies for how much time (in seconds, starting from now) the SMS message is valid and delivery should be attempted. If not specified the default value is 4 days.
|-
|'''X-SMS-Class'''
|Optional
|If specified sets the SMS class. Class 0 is used for flash SMSes, class 3 is used for normal messages. The use of other classes has to be evaluated.
|-
|'''X-SMS-Concatenate-RefID'''
|Optional
|In UDH Concatenate IE, specifies the Reference Id of the split message
|-
|'''X-SMS-Concatenate-Total-Messages'''
|Optional
|In UDH Concatenate IE, specifies the number of messages in which the main message is split
|-
|'''X-SMS-Concatenate-Sequence-Number'''
|Optional
|In UDH Concatenate IE, specifies the sequence number of this messages
|-
|'''Content-Type'''
|Optional
|Defines the content type; Only ''text/plain'' is currently supported
|-
|'''Content-Transfer-Encoding'''
|Optional
|Defines the content encoding, valid values are:
* ''7bit'': 7-bit ASCII text
* ''hex'': Hex-Encoded text
* ''base64'': Base64-encoded text
* ''quoted-printable'': Quoted-printable escaping
|-
|'''Content'''
'''Content2'''
'''ContentN'''
|Mandatory
|The SMS body in the encoding specified in the Content-Transfer-Encoding or 7-bit ASCII if that header is missing.
|-
|}

''IMPORTANT'': Asterisk Manager Interface does NOT support line lengths greater that 80 characters, including the header name, thus, it is mandatory to split the '''Content''' header in more headers with at most 65 characters each, unfortunately the splitting is supported starting from vstuff 1.0.0 which is not yet released. Please use a snapshot in the meantime.
''FIXME!!'' This statement needs to be confirmed. Asterisk version 1.4.14 allows a message of 160 char in one single Content: line. Will a message of size > 160 trigger more than 1 SMS?

===Response statuses===

=====Success=====
* 201 Message Sent

=====Temporary failures =====
* 400 Network out of order
* 401 Module is not ready
* 402 Module is not registered
* 403 Module is already sending a message
* 404 Cannot find an available module
* 405 Cannot allocate message
* 406 Out of memory

=====Permanent failures=====
* 501 Cannot find module
* 502 Services Center number not set
* 503 Cannot open iconv context
* 504 Invalid Content-Type
* 505 Unsupported content-Type
* 506 Unsupported Content-Transfer-Encoding
* 507 Charset conversion error
* 508 Cannot find huntgroup
* 509 Content: header missing
* 510 To: header missing
* 511 Message too big
* 512 Unspecified message preparation error

== Example of a SMS sending session ==

===Authentication===

 [root@voismart-4-000000 chan_vgsm]# telnet localhost 5038
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
 Escape character is '^]'.
 Asterisk Call Manager/1.0
 Action: login
 Username: sms
 Secret: sms
 
 Response: Success
 Message: Authentication accepted

===Simple ASCII message===

 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +393471234567
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=ASCII
 Content: Ciao, questo e' un SMS. Niente caratteri 8-bit, qui.
 
 Status: 201
 X-SMS-Reference: 22
 Response: Success
 Message: Message sent

===UTF-8 encoded message with characters in the GSM alphabet===

 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +393471234567
 X-SMS-ME: vodafone
 X-SMS-Class: 3
 X-SMS-SMCC-Number: +393492000200
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content: VGVzdCBVVEYtOCBlbmNvZGluZyB3aXRoIGNoYXJhY3RlcnMgaW4gdGhlIEdTTSBhbHBoY
 Content2: WJldC4gQWNjZW50czogw6DDqMOsw7LDuSwgR3JlZWsgTGV0dGVyczogzqbOk86bzqnOo
 Content3: M6ozqPOmM6eLCBPdGhlcjogwqXCo8OHw5jDuMOFw6XigqzDhsOmw5/DicKkCg==

===UTF-8 encoded message with characters outside the GSM alphabet===

 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +393471234567
 X-SMS-ME: vodafone
 X-SMS-Class: 3
 X-SMS-SMCC-Number: +393492000200
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Content: Q2hhcnMgb3V0c2lkZSBHU00gY2hhcnNldC4gQXJhYjog27Hbstuz27Tbtdu227fbuNu5L
 Content2: CBIZWI6INeQ15HXkteT15TXldeW15fXmNeZCg==

===Concatenated messages===

 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +393471234567
 X-SMS-ME: vodafone
 X-SMS-Concatenate-RefID: 58
 X-SMS-Concatenate-Total-Messages: 2
 X-SMS-Concatenate-Sequence-Number: 1
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=ASCII
 Content: This is message part 1 of 2, that will be followed by part 2 of 2 which
 Content2:  will be sent later.
 
 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +393471234567
 X-SMS-ME: vodafone
 X-SMS-Concatenate-RefID: 58
 X-SMS-Concatenate-Total-Messages: 2
 X-SMS-Concatenate-Sequence-Number: 2
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=ASCII
 Content:  This is part 2 of 2, the message is now complete. We can thus send up
 Content2: to 255 parts for a total of 40,800 charaters (for just 38 Euros!)

===Sending message using a huntgroup===
 Action: vgsm_sms_tx
 To: +34600123456
 X-SMS-ME: huntgroup:safaricom
 Content-type: text/plain; charset=ASCII
 Content: This message is sent using one of the several ME in the group safaricom

=vgsm_sms_rx Event=

On reception of an inbound SMS (SMS-DELIVERY) the message will also be reported as a manager event, however, acknowledgment still relies on SMS spooler to handle the message. This event is generated starting from 0.21.0

Here follows an example of a received SMS via the manager interface:

 Event: vgsm_sms_rx
 Privilege: call,all
 Received: from GSM module vodafone2, registered on 22210 (Vodafone, Italy); Wed, 20 Jun 2007 19:40:14 +0200
 From: <+393471234567@sms.voismart.it>
 Subject: SMS message
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
 Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2007 19:39:25 +0200
 X-SMS-Message-Type: SMS-DELIVER
 X-SMS-Sender-NP: ISDN telephony
 X-SMS-Sender-TON: International
 X-SMS-Sender-Number: +393471234567
 X-SMS-SMCC-NP: ISDN telephony
 X-SMS-SMCC-TON: International
 X-SMS-SMCC-Number: +393492000429
 X-SMS-More-Messages-To-Send: yes
 X-SMS-Reply-Path: no
 X-SMS-User-Data-Header-Indicator: no
 X-SMS-Status-Report-Indication: no
 Content: SG8gY2hpYW1hdG8gYWxsZSAxOTozOSBkZWwgMjAvMDYvMDcuIEluZm9ybWF6aW9uZSBncmF0dWl0YSBkZWwgc2Vydml6aW8gQ0hJQU1BTUkgZGkgVm9kYWZvbmUu

=vgsm_me_state Event=

Whenever a ME (GSM module) changes working state, an event is generated. Here is an example of such type of events:

 Event: vgsm_me_state
 Privilege: call,all
 X-vGSM-ME-State: POWERING_OFF
 X-vGSM-ME-Old-State: READY
 X-vGSM-ME-State-Change-Reason: Asterisk shutdown

The currently implemented states are:

 CLOSED
 OFF
 POWERING_ON
 POWERING_OFF
 RESETTING
 WAITING_INITIALIZATION
 INITIALIZING
 READY
 WAITING_SIM
 WAITING_PIN
 FAILED

=vgsm_net_state Event=

Whenever the registration status of a GSM module changes, a '''vgsm_net_state''' event is generated. This event is available starting from 0.21.0.
Here follows an example of such event:

 Event: vgsm_net_state
 Privilege: call,all
 X-vGSM-GSM-Registration: REGISTERED_HOME

Valid registration states are:

* NOT_SEARCHING
* NOT_REGISTERED
* REGISTERED_HOME
* UNKNOWN
* REGISTRATION_DENIED
* REGISTERED_ROAMING
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd want the same encoding to be used by Tcl and by the far end program that you're using at the moment; it's pretty rare for other programs in-between (such as `ssh` or `telnet`) to do much other than carry the majority of bytes through unchanged. If the other side expects to be UTF-8, Tcl should be told to use UTF-8 on that channel. In theory, you can put the channel into binary mode and use `encoding convertto utf-8` to generate the bytes to write… but that's horrible and easy to get wrong so it should be avoided when you're not doing something complicated.

It's not very well documented, but Expect's spawn IDs are (a special type of) Tcl channels. That means you can, after the `spawn`, do this once:

```
# Assuming you're not in a procedure; use $::spawn_id otherwise
fconfigure $spawn_id -encoding utf-8
```

and everything should Just Work™ from there on.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying and Thank You!
I tried without good results.
I tried verified that it is only the client-telnet in centos(el5) to give me this problem, it seems to be coded differently. When I write "è", it appears "C (" right in the console. To work around I tried to set it(telnet) in binary mode(however the coding problem seems solved), but once I enter the AMI console it cannot send the written commands

Comment: EDIT: maybe, i'm not understand this comment  $::spawn_id otherwise